# как ограничить масштабируемость экрана в android

Tags: android, экран

в android можно масштабировать текст и размер экрана, у меня есть участок, на котором располагается очень много кнопок, от чего мне нужно отключить подобную возможность, с текстом всё понятно использовать dp, а не sp, но как быть с размером экрана[image]

речь идёт о display size, что на картинке

Comment: Интересный вопрос... Первая мысль - все размеры указывать в `px`. Так точно никакие параметры девайса ничего не изменят. Однако такое подойдёт только для небольшой части кода, для пары экранов, например, не для всего приложения, ибо поддержка такой разметки превратится в адЪ. Если надо сделать для всего приложения такое (что опять таки не рекомендуется, т.к. настройка такая не просто так сделана), то посмотрите код из ответа тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50306032/3212712

Comment: Код из ссылки действительно работает, но я нашёл проблему там по сути приравнивают неизменный xdpi к изменяемомут densitydpi, однако на моем телефоне, к примеру, эти значение вообще никогда неравны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ из комментария работает лишь в эмуляторах, поэтому я копнул глубже и нашел относительно хорошее решение:

```
val configuration = getResources().getConfiguration()
    val metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
    Log.d("TAG", metrics.toString() + " " + getResources().getConfiguration())
    when (resources.displayMetrics.xdpi) { //change size to ignore display size
        in 1..120 -> {
            configuration.densityDpi = 120
        }
        in 121..160 -> {
            configuration.densityDpi = 160
        }
        in 161..240 -> {
            configuration.densityDpi = 240
        }
        in 241..320 -> {
            configuration.densityDpi = 320
        }
        in 321..480 -> {
            configuration.densityDpi = 480
        }
        in 481..640 -> {
            configuration.densityDpi = 640
        }
    }
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics)
```